# Get error "object is not subscriptable" when accessing tuple element. Error depends on usage

Tags: python, tuples, google-colaboratory

Using a list of tuples. When accessing elements of tuple, get error message sometimes.
How is access conditional on later code?
The error message: "TypeError: 'Unit' object is not subscriptable" on line
item_wallname = unit[0]

```
wallList = ["L1", "T1"]

unitList = [("L1",1,"corner_out",.5),
("L1",2,"wall",2),
("L1",3,"window_a",2),
("L1",4,"wall",1),
("T1",1,"wall",8.5)]

for wallname in wallList:
  for unit in unitList: 
    item_wallname = unit[0]               # error line
    if item_wallname == wallname:
      item_unitID = unit[1]
      item_unit_name = unit[2] 
      item_unit_outblocks = unit[3]  
      print("\nunit: " + " " + str(item_wallname) + " " + str(item_unitID))

      makeWallUnit(item_wallname, item_unitID, item_unit_name, item_unit_outblocks)
```

If the line makeWallUnit is active, the error occurs. If it's commented, this output is made:

```
unit:  L1 1

unit:  L1 2

unit:  L1 3

unit:  L1 4

unit:  T1 1
```

Edit, add other code:

```
def makeWallUnit(wall_name, id, name, blocks):
  print("makeWallUnit()")
  unitObj = makeUnit(wall_name, dir, id, name, blocks)
def makeUnit(wall_name, dir, id, name, blocks):
  print('makeUnit()')

  ut = Unit(wall_name, dir, id, name, blocks)

  unitList.append(ut)
  return ut

class Unit:
  def __init__(self, direction, wall_name, unitid, unitname, blocks):
    self.direction = direction
    self.wall_name = wall_name
    self.itemID = unitid
    self.unit_name = unitname
    self.blocks = blocks
    self.inches = blocks * 16
    self.left = 0
    self.right = 0
    self.start = 0
    self.end = 0
```

Comment: My guess is that `makeWallUnit` is modifying the global `unitList`.  That's why globals are bad.

Comment: Need to show what your function does and also show the stack trace of the error

Comment: We need a [mre] of your issue, the code you've posted isn't enough for us to see the issue on our own.

Comment: @TimRoberts it's also why adding or removing elements from a list while iterating over it is bad.

Comment: My question is, The error seems to be for accessing the tuple element. It seems to work in the for block. But when other functions are called there's a problem.

Comment: And that's exactly what happened.  Do you see the problem?  Your original `unitList` is a list of tuples.  But `makeUnit` appends an object to that.  When your loop gets to the object, it should be no surprise that you can't refer to `unit[0]`.  Perhaps you meant to have your original `unitList` be a list of objects instead of a list of tuples?

Comment: Your code gets through all the tuples just fine, but by the time it gets to the end of the tuples, it starts reading the `Unit` objects that were added by `makeUnit`.  This, by the way, is an infinite loop; each loop adds another element to the list.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, Thanks, the unitList in function makeUnit was the wrong name. It should have been a new list of ut objects.

Comment: Or, perhaps, a new `UnitList` object that keeps track of the list on its own?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an error message if the same name is given to two different kinds of lists? In this case, unitList is first a list of tuples, then in a called function it's appending ut objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
unitList.append(ut)
```

this line is giving you the error, it appends an `Unit` object to `unitList` during iteration. i.e. it appends `Unit` objects to the list of tuples, so it becomes [tuple, tuple, .., Unit, Unit, ..]
and then, in future iterations, when code gets to `item_wallname = unit[0]` its no longer doing `(some tuple)[0]` but instead `ut[0]`, which from what I can see is not an iterable object.

Hope this helps explain your issue :)